# Ruby - Checking a hash key/value pair doesn't already exist before adding to a hash

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, key-value

Ruby newbie here! I have a beginners challenge for a very basic password manager that I've had a complete mind blank trying to solve. One of the methods that needs to be defined is that it can ensure all service names and passwords are unique.

Snippet below is where the first version from a previous challenge left off which I THINK will help as a foundation to build on (I've added a comment line where I think the additional pieces will go from there).

```
  def initialize
    @passwords = {}
  end

  def add(service, password)
    #something here to check hash before adding to @passwords hash?????
    return @passwords[service] = password
    end
  end

  def services
    @passwords.keys 
  end

end
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated! Do let me know if any further context is needed etc. First time reaching out in here so still getting used to it all!

Thanks folks :)

Comment: Do you just want to know, whether a certain key already exists in the Hash, or whether a certain key exists **and** has a certain value. In general, you want the former (the latter does not make much sense in your context), but taken your question literally, you meant the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
def add(service, password)
  if @passwords.key?(service)
    puts "Error: A password for #{service} does already exist."
  else
    @passwords[service] = password
  end
end
```

Comment: `@passwords.has_key?(service)` is an alias.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if `@passwords[service] == password` and `password` is not `nil` to avoid the case when `@passwords[service]` is `nil` and `password` is `nil` so that not to have `nil == nil` comparison as [user1934428](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934428/user1934428) mentioned in comments section.

```rb
def add(service, password)
  return if @passwords[service] == password && password
  @passwords[service] = password
end
```

Or more tricky

```rb
@passwords.to_a.include?([service, password])
```

```rb
def add(service, password)
  return if @passwords.to_a.include?([service, password])
  @passwords[service] = password
end
```

Or monkey patch `Hash` class

```rb
class Hash
  def has_pair?(key, value)
    key?(key) && self[key] == value
  end
end
```

```rb
def add(service, password)
  return if @passwords.has_pair?(service, password)
  @passwords[service] = password
end
```

Comment: The first version would fail, if you have a Hash which does have an entry for `service`, but that entry is `nil`, **and** `password` is `nil` as well; or, more general, if `password` happens to be that value which the Hash is configured to return for a missing key.